# Grouping Problem given a list of Objects which should meet all the given constraints

Tags: java, algorithm, java-stream, big-o

I was asked to write a program given the list of objects and group them w.r.to given constraints.

Returns a list of pages of loans, subject to the following constraints:
  * Each page has at most `pageSize` items.
  * A preapproved loan must be the first item on each page if one
    is available. Preapproved loans cannot show up in any other position 
    other than first. Make new pages if necessary.
  * A lender appears at most once on each page. Make new pages if 
    necessary.
  * Without violating the above constraints, return loans sorted in 
    increasing APR since lower is better.

```
private static List<Loan> loans = Arrays.asList(
        new Loan(0.23, "Wells Fargo", false),
        new Loan(0.24, "Wells Fargo", true),
        new Loan(0.21, "Upstart", false),
        new Loan(0.19, "LendingTree", false),
        new Loan(0.20, "Upstart", true),
        new Loan(0.25, "Wells Fargo", true),
        new Loan(0.28, "Bank of America", true),
        new Loan(0.29, "Wells Fargo", false)
);
```

The returned list of lists should be below.

```
private static List<List<Loan>> correctPagingFor3LoansPerPage = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Loan(0.20, "Upstart", true),
                    new Loan(0.19, "LendingTree", false),
                    new Loan(0.23, "Wells Fargo", false)
            ),
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Loan(0.24, "Wells Fargo", true),
                    new Loan(0.21, "Upstart", false)
            ),
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Loan(0.25, "Wells Fargo", true)
            ),
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Loan(0.28, "Bank of America", true),
                    new Loan(0.29, "Wells Fargo", false)
            )
   );
```

So for that, I have written the below program. Below is the full program including the Loan class. Please note that I have added the added property (boolean) to the Loan object. I was given without it, and also I want to know if there is an easy way by just using the java 8 streams and make it fewer lines of code than the below. Please also suggest if there is a better solution in terms of time and space complexity.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Loan {
    double apr;
    String lender;
    boolean preApproved;

    public boolean isAdded() {
        return added;
    }

    public void setAdded(boolean added) {
        this.added = added;
    }

    boolean added;

    public Loan(double apr, String lender, boolean preApproved) {
        this.apr = apr;
        this.lender = lender;
        this.preApproved = preApproved;
    }

    public double getApr() {
        return this.apr;
    }

    public String getLender() {
        return this.lender;
    }

    public boolean getPreApproved() {
        return this.preApproved;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Loan(" + this.apr + ", " + this.lender + ", " + this.preApproved + ")";
    }
}

class Solution {
    private static List<Loan> loans = Arrays.asList(
            new Loan(0.23, "Wells Fargo", false),
            new Loan(0.24, "Wells Fargo", true),
            new Loan(0.21, "Upstart", false),
            new Loan(0.19, "LendingTree", false),
            new Loan(0.20, "Upstart", true),
            new Loan(0.25, "Wells Fargo", true),
            new Loan(0.28, "Bank of America", true),
            new Loan(0.29, "Wells Fargo", false)
    );

    private static List<List<Loan>> correctPagingFor3LoansPerPage = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Loan(0.20, "Upstart", true),
                    new Loan(0.19, "LendingTree", false),
                    new Loan(0.23, "Wells Fargo", false)
            ),
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Loan(0.24, "Wells Fargo", true),
                    new Loan(0.21, "Upstart", false)
            ),
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Loan(0.25, "Wells Fargo", true)
            ),
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Loan(0.28, "Bank of America", true),
                    new Loan(0.29, "Wells Fargo", false)
            )
    );

    // Returns a list of pages of loans, subject to the following constraints:
    // * Each page has at most `pageSize` items.
    // * A preapproved loan must be the first item on each page if one
    //   is available. Preapproved loans cannot show up in any other position other than first. Make new pages if necessary.
    // * A lender appears at most once on each page. Make new pages if necessary.
    // * Without violating the above constraints, return loans sorted in increasing APR since lower is better.
    public static List<List<Loan>> getPages(List<Loan> loans, int pageSize) {
        List<List<Loan>> pages = new ArrayList<List<Loan>>();
        loans.sort(new APRSorter());

        //first step create the lists based on the pre-approval.
        for (Loan loan : loans) {
            if(loan.getPreApproved()){
                List<Loan> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
                innerList.add(loan);
                loan.setAdded(true);
                pages.add(innerList);
            }
        }
        loans.stream().filter(m -> !m.isAdded()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        for(int j=0; j< pages.size(); j++){
            List<Loan> innerList = pages.get(j);
            for(Loan loan: loans){
                while(innerList.size()<pageSize && !loan.isAdded()
                        && !innerList.stream().map(m -> m.getLender())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(loan.getLender())){
                    innerList.add(loan);
                    loan.setAdded(true);
                }
            }
            loans = loans.stream().filter(m -> !m.isAdded()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        //the below code is to loop thru if none of the objects has preapprove true or majority of them has false
        while(loans.size() > 0){
            for(int i=0; i< loans.size();){
                List<Loan> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
                while(innerList.size() < pageSize && i<loans.size()){
                    if(!innerList.stream().map(m -> m.getLender())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(loans.get(i).getLender())){
                        innerList.add(loans.get(i));
                        loans.get(i).setAdded(true);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                pages.add(innerList);
                break;
            }
            loans = loans.stream().filter(m -> !m.isAdded()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        return pages;
    }

    public static class APRSorter implements Comparator<Loan> {
        public int compare (Loan l1, Loan l2) {
            if(l1.getApr() < l2.getApr() ) return -1;
            if(l1.getApr() > l2.getApr() ) return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (List<Loan> page : getPages(loans, 3)) {
            for (Loan loan : page) {
                System.out.println(loan.toString());
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"given constraints"* - what are the constraints? There is no obvious logic to which objects are in which groups, and if your code isn't correct then I can't expect to read it to work out what the constraints are. Please edit the question to explain why that grouping is the expected output.

Comment: If you can go through the code that I have posted here, it has the given constraints. But anyway, I will edit the question to highlight the constraints.

Comment: This is much more complex than it seems at first glance, because if you have many loans which aren't preapproved, then distributing them while minimizing the number of pages and fullfilling the constraints can be very challenging. Greedy algorithms won't guarantee that you get the best solution and your implementation seems to be greedy. It feels like NP to me.

Comment: E.g. for page size two you have 2 preapproved loans one of lender A and one of B. And you have the following not preapproved loans: 1 A, 1 B, 2 C. Now you have to make sure that at least one of the C is added to one page with a preapproved loan or you will get more than 3 pages.

Comment: @maraca it's not about the number of pages, it's about the items in the page when the given param says max 2 items in a page, then you are free to create as many pages as you want as long as it meets the criteria, but the best thing is to minimize the number of pages too...